# Is there any danger in using the Fatman?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So the Fatman weapon dropped from an awarded lunchbox and I was wondering if using it inside the vault could cause any friendly fire or anything like that.

Answer (score 9):

Nope, the Fatman is safe to fire inside your vault. Just like other area weapons (missile launchers, flamethrowers), it does not damage other dwellers or the rooms. In fact, none of the weapons damage other dwellers or the room itself. Vault-Tec sure does make those things sturdy!

<strike>Fatmen are a bit slow to aim and fire; you won't get more than a couple of shots off at deathclaws, but it will take raiders, molerats, and radroaches down very efficiently.</strike>

Fatmen look like they are slow to aim and fire, but enemies will still take damage the entire time the running aorund the room/aiming/firing animations are playing. *Source: Two Deathclaws dropping dead while six fatmen toting dwellers ran around the room trying to get their shot lined up. No one actually got around to firing the fatman before the surviving deathclaw fled the room.*
[image: Who needs to fire the fat man when you can run around instead?]

When a dweller finally does get a shot off, it looks pretty cool.

Comment: Is 'Farmer' a typo for 'Fatman/Fatmen'?

Comment: @Angzuril yes it is, curse my mobile autocorrect

Comment: Despite the firing animation, I'm not **sure** that the Fatman deals damage any more slowly than other weapons. Even when I've had dwellers alone in rooms with enemies and taking damage (which makes them play a wounded animation instead of firing), I've still noticed those enemies die a lot sooner than they otherwise would. This makes me wonder if attacks and damage are somewhat separate from the animations and if combat is more regular over time.

Comment: @Samthere you are right, the animations are disconnected from the damage entirely. I've updated my post with my experimental results. **tl;dr: enemies dropped dead without any shots fired**

Comment: You could maybe clarify that this is a "damage/time" system?

Comment: Now that there are quests, the animation speed of the fatman is a concern again. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/287728/72346

Answer (score 0):

The explosion from the Fatman won't hurt any of your Dwellers. So it is completely safe for it to be in the vault.

I hope this helped.