# Is the damage calculated as Damage per Second or Damage per Hit?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Every weapon has a certain Damage. But they didn't tell us *what* it exactly means.
**So, does the Damage mean Damage Per Second or Damage per Hit?**

Comment: In the vault, in the wasteland, or on quests?

Comment: Looking especially for the Damage on quests, but also for the in-Vault combat. @OrangeDog

Answer (score 4):

On quests, the weapon damage value is per-round. For weapons with a single hit per round this is easy. For multi-hit weapons (including multi-shot and AoE) the damage is distributed over each hit. Frequency of attack rounds is determined by Agility. The weapon damage is also scaled by Strength.

In the vault, weapons do damage constantly over time regardless of animations or damage type. The DPS should be a function of the average weapon damage and the dweller's Strength, Perception and Agility.

Answer (score 3):

It's damage per hit. Your DPS is calculated using the weapon's damage and your special skills, but I don't have the exact formula.

Although the health bar may decrease over time when the weapon is firing, the total damage will be the damage rating of the weapon.

It's also worth adding that explosive or area of effect weapons, such as the MIRV, deal their damage split between all enemies in a room. For example, say you had a MIRV that did 30 damage and had 3 enemies in the room, they would each take 10 damage every time it fires.

Comment: Not to disagree, but this is not at all obvious from playing the game. Have a source?

Comment: So this means that Rifles deal triple Damage than Melee Weapons. And the Gatling Laser would be *terribly* fatal.

Comment: I don't think that the Damage from Area Attack Weapons splits. I've tested this in a Quest. For example, 5 Mole Rats took the same individual Damage as 3 Mole Rats. An important note, @DCShannon , is that wikis don't contain info on this.

Comment: @John The problem with that example is that if there are more enemies in  a room, then they have less HP. So the five mole rats had less HP than the three mole rats, and the damage done may have looked the same on their HP bars but in reality it was less.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hit" while in the vault.

Comment: @OrangeDog Then on quests.